# Vim - ctags: tag not found

Tags: vim, ctags

I want to use Ctags for a Zend framework project. I executed this command : `ctags -R ./* ../ZendFramework/*`to create a list of tags, but the problem is when I press `Ctrl-]` on a class or method I get this error: `ctags: tag not found`

I checked the `tags` file and all classes/methods/variables are listed. The `tags` files is located in the root of the project. Should I load it manullay when I open a file?

Comment: For dealing with ctags you might want to use plugin Indexer: http://goo.gl/kixRn . It provides painless automatic tags generation for the whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date. Check my another answer for some details: http://goo.gl/pG9OP

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yes, you should tell Vim where to find your `tags` file with something like:

```
:set tags=/path/to/tags
```

This is not very optimal, though. This line in your `~/.vimrc` should help:

```
set tags=./tags,tags;$HOME
```

It tells Vim to look for a `tags` file in the directory of the current file, in the current directory and up and up until your `$HOME` (that's the meaning of the semicolon), stopping on the first hit.

Comment: You might also find `set autochdir` useful.

Comment: In my case, `set tags=./tags` works with vim7.x but not with vim8.0. 
In vim8.0 `set tags=tags` works.

Comment: :set tags=/path/to/tags
work for me. I met this issue in  my ubuntu16,but not in my ubuntu22

Comment: :set tags=/path/to/tags  only absolute path work in this way

Answer (score 7):

The `'tags'` variable must point to your `tags` file. See `:help 'tags'`.
An example to add the path to your tags file:

```
:set tags+=$HOME/yourpath/tags
```

Answer (score 0):

I Faced the same problem few days ago. I was applying `ctags` shortcuts in a `.c` file and I was getting this error while doing so. I googled the error and found that the `ctags` was not installed. But the `ctags` is present in my server. I tried moving the ctag folder to the trunk which i'm currently working and this trick resolved my problem.

steps:

1. go to your home folder and enter "where is ctags"
2. it will display the path of the ctags file.
3. copy that file and move the same to the directory which you are working in
   i hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

work for me

```
sudo apt-get install ctags
set tags=~/.vim/plugin
```