# How to use ctags to generate tags for non-standard python packages?

Tags: python, vim, package, ctags

I use pip to manage my python packages, and my all of these packages are located in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. I run this command `ctags -R -o ~/codes/python/pytags /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` to generate tags for python packages, and add `set tags=./tags,~/codes/python/pytags`
 in my vimrc file, but when I run `:ptag numpy` in vim, It still shows "tag not found", anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975316/vim-ctags-tag-not-found